# Trying to remove the underline from a visited link in phpBB

Tags: hyperlink, phpbb, underline

I don't know if it's possible, or advisable even if it is. I'm using phpBB 3.2.3 I've replaced every instance of the word underline in styles/prosilver/theme/links.css with the word none. After doing that, I then changed the following line of code,

```
.postlink {
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

to

```
.postlink {
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

And I changed the following code from styles/prosilver/theme/colours.css

```
.postlink {
border-bottom-color: #368AD2;
color: #368AD2;
}

.postlink:visited {
border-bottom-color: #5D8FBD;
color: #5D8FBD;
}
```

to

```
.postlink {
color: #368AD2;
}

.postlink:visited {
color: #5D8FBD;
}
```

I then purged the forum's cache and ctrl+f5'd my browser. Links now appear without an underline but only until I click, after which an underline appears. Is there any way for me to stop that underline from appearing? Or should I even try?

Comment: You're not looking for border, you're looking for 'text-decoration: underline;'

Comment: Well as I say anyway, I found the answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer elsewhere on this site!

I had to add the following line of code to the bottom of styles/prosilver/theme/links.css

```
a, a:hover, a:active, a:visited, a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

That did the trick! Now I'm not getting any underline at all!